# Tour: SanFrancisco, LA, SanDiego, Las Vegas, Grand Canyon -> insider sights

Tags: sightseeing, tips-and-tricks, road-trips

In this summer my girlfriend and me will be on vacation for three weeks in the USA / California. We want to make a round trip and already booked a flight to SanFrancisco. From there we plan to rent a car and make a Trip from SanFran to LA (via Highway 1) to SanDiego to Grand Canyon and finally to Las Vegas.

I think we know about all the "common" sights - which also can be found on tripadvisor and other sites on the internet. But for us its maybe the only visit in California (and Nevada -> Las Vegas and a bit of Arizona -> Grand Canyon) in our life, because we're from Germany and the trip will not be very cheap. So my Question is if you have any tips for us of things we should do or places we should visit and are not well known. The tips should  roughly fit for our tour route. So we are not looking for tips like 'drive over the golden gate bridge' or 'go to alcatraz'. ;-)

I know my question is a bit broad. I hope it is not too broad, so that the question has to be closed. I would be thankful for every tip!

kind regards!

Comment: You can try the Ethyl M chocolate factory and gardens, I used to work there and know they made a large investment in the gardens.  Same family as Mars Gmbh.  It's in the Vegas burbs.

Comment: There's also a rattlesnake farm off I15 which is interesting.

Comment: Area 51 not too far North of Vegas. Death Valley a must see day trip if you can spare the day. Go to the Grand Canyon via Sedona if possible. Marvellous landscapes. Be sure to drive at least part of Route 66 - all the small towns have R66 memorablia (which is thus good and bad). We even saw Elvis lounging against an Edsel but he was very wooden and non-communicative. Old dead ish wind turbines in Altimont Pass. Highway 1?  - drive the Big Sur Rd if at all possible (Do you know the way to San Jose? - A: Take the 101). Hearst Castle. | Mission San Juan Capistrano - utter magic. Be sure to ....

Comment: ... eat at at least one IHOP, withdraw some money at Wells Fargo (!), View the Boulder Dam (Hoover?), Armagosa Opera House!!!, Armagosa Baptist Church !!!!!!!!!!, Dante's View? - > 1 mile to valley floor at Badwater - LOOKS easy going.  / Zabriski Point (only because of the movie)(unrelated?), Corner of Hayte & Ashbury - street sign is the only indication of what was, Zig zag steepest street. Ride a cable car, Cross the Golden Gate, photograph Alcatraz. Old Vegas xxx street with dynamic lit roof/ceiling, Careful Kitty's, ...

Comment: i see the question is "on hold" now. To understand why: If i only would ask for some tips in SanFrancisco would it also be put on hold, or would that be ok? As i mentioned: I have a plan. I don't want you to plan my tour. I don't think it is like the WANTA discussion. I am asking for some "secret tips" which also travel agents could not give me...

Comment: @frupfrup Yes, I imagine it would be. The question is both too broad and too vague; there are a million things to do in San Francisco, and you also haven't defined what makes something "not well known." The Cloisters art museum in New York is not well-known compared to the Met or the Guggenheim,  but it was still visited by 350,000 people last year, not very "secret" at all. This Stack is best for honing down a narrow list of options or asking specific questions about a particular attraction, not developing lists of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Several off beat attractions spring to mind

In Sanfrancisco the Russian museum

http://www.atlasobscura.com/places/museum-of-russian-culture

In Sandiego the botanical gardens are really great with a very peaceful atmosphere

http://www.sandiegotraveltips.com/public/San_Diego_Botanic_Garden_and_Self_Realization_Fellowship_Temple.cfm

I also love Sandiego zoo, which is world famous, but is a traditional tourist destination.

And in Vegas you have lots of choice of weird and wonderful, but my three favourite places

The atomic testing museum

http://www.nationalatomictestingmuseum.org

The museum of erotica

http://m.eroticheritagemuseumlasvegas.com/#!About|about_page   This link might not be super work friendly!

And. The parumph valley vineyard.

http://www.pahrumpwinery.com

Have a great trip.